# How do I pass R.drawable.XXX value to a function in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-animation, drawable

Here's my code:

```
private fun roomChange(animation: Int)
{
    val rocketImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2).apply {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation)
        foxanim = background as AnimationDrawable
        foxanim.start()
    }
}
```

I have anim.xml file and would like to pass it to a function but "animation" is an unresolved reference. How would I go about passing it correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the file is called ``anim.xml`` then your drawable ID is ``R.drawable.anim``

Comment: I mean I have multiple xml files with different names for animations and I want to do something like that: roomChange(anim) or roomChange(run). Would that be possible?

Comment: Ohhh I see what you're doing - you just use ``setBackgroundResource(animation)``. IDs like ``R.drawable.anim`` or ``R.id.imageView`` are just variables that hold ints, so you can just pass the int directly. You'd call ``roomChange`` with ``roomChange(R.drawable.anim)``, which is basically just calling the function with the right int value. If you want it to be more readable, so you don't need the ``R.drawable`` bit, you could make an enum class that has a value for each animation resource (I can give you an example in an answer if that's something you want but you don't know what I mean)

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know I could pass ID like that directly, now it works! So thank you so much! I don't know how to make the enum class exactly but It's not as important so I wouldn't like to bother you :P

Comment: It's cool it'll only take a minute! It's a good technique to know

Comment: Oh hey don't mark that answer as correct, it's not answering the question! Plus going off the timestamps, the others started answering before I commented. They're better answers for anyone with the same question as you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.drawable.whatever` is just an Int. That's all you need to pass along to `setBackgroundResource()`.

If you want the IDE to help prevent you from accidentally passing the wrong kind of argument, you can also add `@AnimRes`. Then in certain cases when it can detect that you are passing an Int that is not an animation resource ID, it will show an error.

```
private fun roomChange(@AnimRes animation: Int)
{
    val rocketImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2).apply {
        setBackgroundResource(animation)
        foxanim = background as AnimationDrawable
        foxanim.start()
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the enum thing I mentioned in the comments:

```
// Basic enum with an animation resource property - add one for each anim
// The @AnimRes annotation is optional, just gives you a warning if you use something else
enum class StateAnimation(@AnimRes val animationId: Int) {
    ANIM(R.drawable.animation),
    RUN(R.drawable.run)
}

...

// set your function to take one of your animation definitions instead
private fun roomChange(stateAnim: StateAnimation) {
    // pull out the resource ID from the passed animation
    setBackgroundResource(stateAnim.animationId)
}

// call your function using the animation you want
roomChange(StateAnimation.RUN)
```

The idea here is you can create an enum class that defines all your animations, so you can name each one however you like, and they all have a resource ID for the animation they represent. Then you pass one of those to your function instead, and the function can refer to its resource ID

This way you get code completion and type checking (you have to pass one of the `StateAnimation`s, not any other animation ID, resource ID, or random int). Your code can be cleaner because `StateAnimation.RUN` is pretty clear (you might want to rename that but you get the idea), and it's safer than passing a string like `"run"` and converting that into a resource lookup which may or may not exist

And if you want, you can just `import` everything in `StateAnimation` (put your cursor on `RUN` and do `Alt+Enter` or click the lightbulb and it'll offer to do it for you) and then you can just call `roomChange(RUN)` and it's nice and concise!

Comment: It will be so nice when/if [this YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16768) is implemented. They just updated it to target 1.7.0 last week, so there's hope!

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh yeah that would be sweet, best of both worlds really! I sometimes like writing the enum/sealed class name in full for clarity, but being able to avoid importing it and still get that shorthand where there's context, that would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this :

```
private fun roomChange(animation: Drawable) {
    val rocketImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2).apply {
        background = animation
        foxanim = background as AnimationDrawable
        foxanim.start()
    }
}
```